# Matching Strings in pandas to generate a new column with values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to determine whether or not a particular column contains the first three letters of a string and then generate an new value in a new column based on whether or not the first two characters in the strings match. Right now my DF looks like this:

```
Foo    Bar
A      Sock    
B      Shoe    
C      Glove   
D      Hat
```

But I want to generate this third column (Zoo):

```
Foo    Bar    Zoo
A      Sock    3
B      Shoe    3
C      Glove   2
D      Hat     1
```

Right now my code looks like this but it isn't working:

```
def f(row):
    if row['Bar'] str.startswith('Sh'| 'So'):
         val = 3
    elif row['Bar'] str.startswith('Gl'):
          val = 2
    else: 
           val = 1
       return val    


df['Zoo'] = df.apply(f, axis = 0 )
```

The return value is supposed to be if 'Sh' or 'So' are included then return val = 3.

I tried this:

```
df.loc[df['Bar'].str.startswith('Sh|So'), ['Zoo']] = 3
df.loc[df['Bar'].str.startswith('Gl'), ['Zoo']] = 2
```

but I really need it as an if statement so that the 'else' can catch everything that doesn't match my strings. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [14]: df
Out[14]: 
  Foo    Bar
0   A   Sock
1   B   Shoe
2   C  Glove
3   D    Hat

In [15]: ZOO_VAL = {
    "So": 3,
    "Sh": 3,
    "Gl": 2
}

In [16]: df['Zoo'] = df['Bar'].map(lambda x: ZOO_VAL.get(x[:2], 1))

In [17]: df
Out[17]: 
  Foo    Bar  Zoo
0   A   Sock    3
1   B   Shoe    3
2   C  Glove    2
3   D    Hat    1
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can try this by using `replace`

```
df.assign(Zoo=pd.to_numeric(df.Bar.str[:2].replace({'So':3,'Sh':3,'Gl':2}),errors='coerce').fillna(1))
Out[108]: 
  Foo    Bar  Zoo
0   A   Sock  3.0
1   B   Shoe  3.0
2   C  Glove  2.0
3   D    Hat  1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I like grechut's answer above but to fix your original code:

```
def f(row):
    if row.startswith('Sh') or row.startswith('So'):
        val = 3
    elif row.startswith('Gl'):
        val = 2
    else: 
        val = 1
    return val 

df['Bar'].apply(f)
```